# how to use php to read xml file

Tags: php, xml

Trying to echo all AudioTracks data from xml file. 
Also trying to get the the EffectiveName Value.

I have tried the followings, but do not know how:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->load('1.xml');
$Tracks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('AudioTrack');
foreach($Tracks as $AudioTrack) {
    echo $AudioTrack->firstChild->firstChild->data . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pton MajorVersion="4" MinorVersion="9.5_326" SchemaChangeCount="4" 
Creator="Pton" Revision="io2f5nghga">
<LiveSet>
    <OverwriteProtectionNumber Value="2305" />
    <LomId Value="0" />
    <LomIdView Value="0" />
    <Tracks>
        <AudioTrack Id="14">
            <LomId Value="0" />
            <LomIdView Value="0" />
            <EnvelopeModePreferred Value="false" />
            <TrackDelay>
                <Value Value="0" />
                <IsValueSampleBased Value="false" />
            </TrackDelay>
            <Name>
                <EffectiveName Value="1-Audio" />
                <UserName Value="" />
                <Annotation Value="" />
            </Name>
```

Comment: I'd use SimpleXml for this, https://3v4l.org/Bt0aM, if that works I can put it as an answer... or maybe you don't want all tracks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your node values are all contained within a single attribute, and you want to output all of the data, you could do something like the following.

```
$Tracks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('AudioTrack');
foreach($Tracks as $AudioTrack) {
    $audioTrackAttributes = $AudioTrack->attributes;
    echo 'AudioTrack '.$audioTrackAttributes->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br/>';
    $TrackChildNodes = $AudioTrack->childNodes;
    foreach($TrackChildNodes as $child) {
        outputNode($child);
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}

function outputNode($nextNode)
{
    $childAttributes = $nextNode->attributes;

    if ( !empty($childAttributes) && $childAttributes->length > 0 ) { 
        echo $nextNode->nodeName . ': ' . $childAttributes->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br/>';
    } else {
        echo $nextNode->nodeName . '<br/>';
    }

    $grandchildNodes = $nextNode->childNodes;
    if ( !empty($grandchildNodes) ) {
        foreach($grandchildNodes AS $grandchild) {
            outputNode($grandchild);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

You will need to enclose your data within a document node as well as close the Pton node properly.

```
<document>
    <Pton MajorVersion="4" . . . /> 
    <Etc.></Etc.>
</document>
```

Comment: The documentation here is pretty good: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling with `documentElement`

$dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('AudioTrack');

The documentation says like this

documentElement:

> This is a convenience attribute that allows direct access to the child
>   node that is the document element of the document.